# Java: how to copy a directory but exclude some directories deep inside main directory

Tags: java, directory, copy

Using java, I want to copy whole directory excluding some sub-directories (and all files inside those sub-directories) down file path. How can I do that? I've seen several such questions on SO but using Perl/ANT etc but not using Java.

Comment: "..but using Perl/ANT etc but not using Java." Ant tasks are mostly written in Java.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : I was just going to ask this. Is it possible to call ANT script from Java? On this line Google has thrown some links. Going thru them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [FileUtils.html#copyDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from Apache Commons IO. One of the overloaded versions take [FileFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) instance with single straightforward method to be implemented by you:

```
boolean accept(File pathname)
```

Also look at the list of existing convenient `FileFilter` [implementations](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AbstractFileFilter.html) in Commons IO:

- AgeFileFilter
- AndFileFilter
- CanReadFileFilter
- CanWriteFileFilter
- DelegateFileFilter
- DirectoryFileFilter
- EmptyFileFilter
- FileFileFilter
- HiddenFileFilter
- MagicNumberFileFilter
- NameFileFilter
- NotFileFilter
- OrFileFilter
- PrefixFileFilter
- RegexFileFilter
- SizeFileFilter
- SuffixFileFilter
- WildcardFileFilter
- WildcardFilter

Comment: FileFilter overloading was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way you would in any other language

1. Start at the root of the source directory
2. Go through all children (using Breadth-First-Search for example)
3. If you want to ignore the child, ignore it
   If the child is a directory, use File.mkdir() on that child
   If the child is a file, copy it
     Open the file using a FileInputStream
     Writing the data you read to a new file using a FileOutputStream
4. Repeat with each child directory

Or, you can do this the easy way
1. [Apache FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)
2. [Java File Copy Library](http://filecopylibrary.sourceforge.net/) project