# Check a file path contains a specific directory name in it

Tags: java, file

I'm working with a directory which is checked out from svn.

Ex

HelloWorldProject

- src
- images

I'm manually copying entire files from `images` directory to one directory using `commons-io`

```
for (String fileFromList : imageFiles) {
    FileUtils.copyFile(new File(fileFromList) , new File(destinationFile));
}
```

All the files from images including .svn also getting copied. Is there any way to exclude the file which contains a **directory** name **.svn**? I may use `fileFromList.contains(".svn")` but if there is a file name like `image.svn.check.jpg` will also getting excluded. Is there any way to identify a file path which contains a specific directory name.

Correct me if my understanding is wrong. I searched enough, I couldn't find anwer for this problem. If it's duplicate, I apology for wasted your time.

Comment: How `endsWith` will help me? 
Check this, one of the file path I need to copy
`..images\Back.png`. What I don't want is `.svn\text-base\Back.png.svn-base`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205167/java-how-to-copy-a-directory-but-exclude-some-directories-deep-inside-main-dire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for (String fileFromList : imageFiles) {
    if (!fileFromList.contains("/.svn/")
      FileUtils.copyFile(fileFromList , destinationFile);
}
```

Comment: I feel, String.contains is a risk. I want to avoid it.

Comment: @Pasupathi I don't thik so if you use the slash arround you can be sure that is not a part of a file name or so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude files which has ".svn" as ending this will work:

```
for (String fileFromList : imageFiles) {
        if(!fileFromList.endsWith(".svn")){ 
            FileUtils.copyFile(new File(fileFromList) , new File(destinationFile));
        }
    }
```

If you want to check if a file **is not** in a **directory named ".svn"** (e.g. C://.svn/test.jpg) you should use:

```
for (String fileFromList : imageFiles) {
        if(!fileFromList.contains("/.svn/")){ 
            FileUtils.copyFile(new File(fileFromList) , new File(destinationFile));
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to use `File.separator`. On all OS java uses the normal slash for separating paths.

Comment: I think this might even be incorrect then. Because you are comparing strings. And if Java returns the file-path with slashes and you look for backslashes, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

`Path` extends Iterable , so you can iterate it and check if any parts ends with or equals some conditions